# Mock does not check for function parameters

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, mocking, arguments

I have the following code.   File foo.py has:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
class Foo():
  def foo(self, num):
    time.sleep (10)
    return num + num
```

File mock_test.py has:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from mock import patch
import foo
import unittest

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  @patch('foo.Foo.foo')  # filename, classname, fn name
  def test_one(self, mock_foo):
    mock_foo.return_value = 'mock return value'
    myobj = foo.Foo()
    print (myobj.foo())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

And file regular_test.py has:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import foo
import unittest

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_one(self):
    f = foo.Foo()
    print (f.foo(20))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Now, if I ran regular_test.py, it checks the number of parameters being passed to f.foo()    But mock_test.py does no such thing!    Isn't mock test supposed to be meant only for speedup of function execution?   Why does it not flag an error if I called foo() with 0 arguments or more than 1 argument?

Answer (score 1):

Because `mock_foo` != `Foo.foo`.

`mock_foo` is a completely different implementation of `Foo.foo`. When you are mocking it, you are defining what is supposed to do. Since `mock_foo` is not setup to except any arguments (you have set it up to return a string), the interpreter is not complaining about the missing argument.

> Isn't mock test supposed to be meant only for speedup of function execution?

This statement is not entirely correct. The following is a simple use case of mocking:

```
def bar():
   return rand.randint(0, 10)

def foo(num):
   random = bar()
   return num / random
```

I want to test `foo`, but the output depends on the output of `bar`. What will be the output if `bar()` returns 1? or 10? or 0? To test if `foo` is correct, I can mock `bar()` to return a predefined value, so I *know* what to expect from `foo()`.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks.   How do I set it up to accept the same number of arguments as the function it is supposed to mock?